# Default Matrix Rows Showing In Channel Form

Tags: matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic, channel-form

Is there any way to use Matrix on the front end via a channel form and have 4 rows pre-populated for new entries.

Basically, we want to have a 'milestone' date area with one column with the milestone description and another column for the milestone date.

Each new job has a minimum of 4 milestones: `Concept, Content, Files, Delivery`. Hence, wanting to start with a default set of 4 rows for new entries.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set the minimum rows to 4 in the matrix field config it will display 4, at least I think it works like that in the cp.

Comment: stuartmcd69 - Cheers. We'd like the default 4 rows to also have the default 4 milestone descriptions in the matrix as well, not just 4 empty rows to start with.

Comment: You're likely going to have to introduce ajax to populate the fields. If you want the fields to be pre-populated with EE info you'll have to consider another approach

Comment: stuartmcd69 - Yeah, that's where we got to. Just wanted to check we weren't missing something with Matrix. Cheers.